# hubspot mailing list integration on react

Tags: reactjs, hubspot

I am using hubspot for email integration on my react project.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Footer() {
  const [emailAdded, setEmailAdded] = useState(false);
  const [emailInputValue, setEmailInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="main__footer">
      <div className="secondary__footer">
        <div className="main__text">
          <h1>KEEP UP TO DATE</h1>
          <div className="mobile__text">
            JOIN OUR MAILING LIST TO KEEP UP TO <br />
            DATE WITH THE LATEST NFT RELEASES, <br />
            TRENDS, AND ARBORETUM UPDATES
          </div>
          <div className="join__class">
            <input
              type="text"
              name=""
              id=""
              placeholder="TYPE YOUR EMAIL...."
              className="input_class"
              value={emailInputValue}
              onChange={(e) => setEmailInputValue(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={handleJoinClick}>
              JOIN
            </button>
          </div>
          {emailAdded && <div>Email Added Successfully!</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

What I want is, if the user put his email and click join it should add to my mailing list. I have hubspot portal and form ID. I have tried using below code. I have added the script on the index.html file. How can I make it work? Can anyone help and review my code?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.hbspt) {
      window.hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "eu1",
        portalId: "1396xxxxx",
        formId: "4f8024fa-xxxx-4fcb-912d-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const handleJoinClick = () => {
    const emailInput = document.querySelector(".input_class");
    const joinButton = document.querySelector(".join__class button");
    if (emailInput && joinButton) {
      const userEmail = emailInput.value;
      setEmailAdded(true);
      setEmailInputValue("");
      joinButton.click();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing with the Promise.all() version of deleting all folders could be due to rate limits imposed by the ClickUp API.

Even though you're only deleting a small number of folders, concurrent requests made by Promise.all() may exceed the rate limit.

When you use a for loop with await, the requests are made sequentially, allowing the API to process them within the rate limits.

This is why the for loop version works fine.
To overcome the rate limit issue while using Promise.all(), you can introduce a delay between each request to ensure that you stay within the rate limit.

One approach is to use setTimeout() to introduce a delay before making each request.

Here's an example of how you can modify the deleteAllFolders() function to add a delay between each deletion:

```
async function deleteAllFolders() {
  const teamID = await getWorkspaces();
  const spaceID = await getSpaces(teamID);
  const allFolders = await getFolders(spaceID);

  const promises = allFolders.folders.map(async (folder, index) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, index * 1000)); // Add a delay of 1 second per folder

    return deleteFolder(folder.id);
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

In this example, setTimeout(resolve, index * 1000) adds a delay of 1 second per folder before making the deletion request.
Adjust the delay time as necessary to ensure you stay within the rate limits.

By introducing a delay between each deletion, you should be able to avoid exceeding the rate limit and ensure that all folders are successfully deleted using Promise.all().